# Simplify two boolean expressions

Tags: java, boolean

I got a trouble on simplifying two boolean expressions.

```
boolean sayHi = true;
boolean isValid = someVariable.equals(new exampleClass("hello")) || someVariable.equals(new exampleClass("Hi"));

if (sayHi & !isValid) {
 return;
}
```

How can i simplify this one? I think isValid looks quite big, is there a way to do it? Please help me.

Comment: `Set.of(new exampleClass("hello"), new exampleClass("hi")).contains(someVariable)`.

Comment: Completely unrelated but also worth noting: with your current `if` condition, `isValid` will always be checked regardless of whether `sayHi == false`. If you want to return early when `sayHi == false`, add an `&`.

Comment: @AndyTurner , is this on java 9? currently i am on java 8.

Comment: @iftwMZ or `Arrays.asList(...).contains(someVariable)`.

Comment: `isValid` uses two operands. This is not 'quite big'. But the point of `sayHi`eludes me. It is constant and `true` in the code you posted. You can certainly remove that.

Comment: @user207421 , i gave just an example of sayHi, actually sayHi is a function which sometimes can be false, so it can't be removed from there :)

Comment: This is an incomplete code sample.  Is `sayHi` a constant or can its value change (before or after the if-condition is evaluated)?  What is the implementation of `exampleClass`?  We can infer that `someVariable` is an instance of `exampleClass` - is this correct?  Do you really intend to perform a bitwise AND in the if-condition or should this be an boolean AND operator (i.e. `&&`)?

Comment: So you still only have three operands and three operators. There's nothing to simplify. De Morgan would agree. You can't improve on `(sayHi & !isValid)`, except to use `&&` instead of `&`. Unclear what you;re asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
boolean sayHi = true;
boolean valid = Arrays.asList("hello", "hi").contains(someVariable.getName());

if (sayHi && !valid) {
    return;
}
```

Newer java would use `Set.of` (better semantics, performance).

`isValid` is more a name for a boolean getter.

Assumed is that "hello" and "hi" can be retrieved with a getter.

Comment: Only if you make some massive unstated assumptions about the semantics of `exampleClass.equals()`. And I don't know where you got `getName()` from.

Comment: @user207421 that is very true, and a worthwile comment. However `equals(C("a"))||equals(C("b"))` is a typical code pattern, where one only has a (derived) variable "too far".

Answer (score -2):

```
boolean sayHi = true;

if (sayHi && !someVariable.equals(new exampleClass("hello")) 
          && !someVariable.equals(new exampleClass("Hi"))) 
     return;
```

Comment: You've gone from three operators to four. How is that an improvement?

Comment: @user207421 improvement in performance